# SQL Server Regular expression

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to write a SQL to select the records only if there is NO matching closing braces 
for example if the column `"TEXT_DATA"` has `'tes(ting(sql)select'` and `'tes(ting(sql)sel)ect'` then the select statement should return only `'tes(ting(sql)select'` because it is missing a matching closing brace `")"`.

There can be one or more missing closing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using a regular expression but it'll do the job:

```
Select text_data as [TEXT_DATA], 
    len(text_data)-len(replace(text_data, '(', '')) as [CountOpen], 
    len(text_data)-len(replace(text_data,')','')) as [CountClose] 
    into #temp 
    from table

Select TEXT_DATA from #temp where CountOpen<>CountClose
```

Comment: This will only count number of occurrences of parenthesis, it will not check if those are matching, (open with close). i.e. "))sql((" this will also be vaild with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have complex regular expression support. You cannot check this using TSQL. You will need to write your custom code.